# Finding most common value in array and returning it with the count

Tags: php

```
$input = array(1,1,2,3,2,1,1);
$c = array_count_values($input);
$val = array_search(max($c), $c)
$count =
```

This returns 1 as expected (most common). How would I find out how many times it occurs in the array? There are many similar questions, but none of them were interested in finding the count.

```
echo $val. "ccours". $count . "times";
```

Comment: Uhhm, wouldn't max($c) be the count?

Comment: Or, to return both the most common and the count: `return array($val => $c[$val]);`

Comment: Oh right, that was a bit silly of me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're interpreting the result correctly? Because the function should do exactly, what you need. From the manual:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The result should then be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```